# Dynamic formula cell referencing w/offset

Tags: excel, dynamic, formula, offset, excel-indirect

My formula:

`=IFERROR(OFFSET('**2015**'!$A$1,MATCH($A8,'**2015**'!$A$2:$A$6000,0),0),0)`

I need the parts in bold to be referencing a cell with a drop down (the drop down obviously has different dates which the formula needs to take into account) - which I guess makes it somewhat dynamic.

I have tried the indirect formula but failed to accomplish anything. I have ran out of ideas unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merely adding INDIRECT:

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET(INDIRECT(O2&"!$A$1"),MATCH($A8,INDIRECT(O2&"!$A$2:$A$6000"),0),0),0)
```

Assumes dropdown value is in `O2`.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the INDEX/MATCH over the offset:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & $A1 & "'!$AA:$AA"),MATCH($A8,INDIRECT("'" & $A1 & "'!$A:$A"),0)),0)
```

This will search column A for the matching value and return the corresponding value from column AA in the desired sheet.

Where A1 is the location of your drop down.

Comment: Scott, I need the formula to match the products and then pull data a few columns ahead. How do I do this?

Comment: So what column Specifically?

Comment: The column i need to match is a however the data i need is actually in column aa

Comment: You are a superstar!